# Обработка html как текста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть статья из интернета. В этой статье есть теги code, которыми выделяются конструкции на языке Python. 
Необходимо найти все строки, содержащиеся между тегами `<code>` и `</code>` и найти те строки, которые встречаются чаще всего и вывести их в алфавитном порядке, разделяя пробелами.

Comment: Можете привести пример входных данных?

Comment: @Евгений  [ссылка](view-source:https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python)

Comment: Вам сюда https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ специальная библиотека для работы с HTML